# Transpose only certain columns - data formating

Tags: r

Im trying to modify some data and have the following data now:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2010,2011,2010,2011),A = c(10,11,10,11),B = c(11,12,11,12))


  year        A         B
1 2010        10        11
2 2011        11        12
3 2010        10        11
4 2011        11        12
```

I want it to look like this, but do not know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

```
  company year   Variable
1   A      2010  10           
2   A      2011  11            
3   B      2010  11             
4   B      2011  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -year, 
   names_to = 'company', values_to = 'Variable')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   year company Variable
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1  2010 A             10
2  2010 B             11
3  2011 A             11
4  2011 B             12
5  2010 A             10
6  2010 B             11
7  2011 A             11
8  2011 B             12
```

Comment: Im sorry but, my code for the df were slightly wrong, so I believe your coding suggestion need slight modifications. Could you please update your proposal to the new df?

Comment: @thomas.diridondo updated. that modification is more easier to pivot

Comment: Thank you, it does!